# Select option can't show data in pop up edit

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

i have problem with select option when i click edit button pop up show,but select option can't show data.
so here my screenshot:[image: edit pop up]

mycode:

```html
 <select class="form-control" name="actype">
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
 <?php foreach($actype as $actype) {
 echo '<option value="'.$actype>activity_type_id.'">'.$actype>activity_type_name.'</option>';
  }
   ?>
</select>
```

my ajax:

```js
function edit(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('activity/edit/')?>" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        
        {
            $("[name='activity_detail_id']").val(data[0].activity_detail_id);
            $("[name='actype']").val(data[0].activity_type_id);
            $("[name='activity_name']").val(data[0].activity_name);
            $("[name='project']").val(data[0].project_id);
            $("[name='portion']").val(data[0].portion);
            $('#Modal').modal('show'); 
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Activity');// show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            
            

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

where is my wrong code.and how to resolve it.

Comment: make sure same 'value' field you are assigning in html and jquery both.
can you post the error (if any)?

Comment: no error in debug program,'value' in html and jquery same.error only in select option,you can see above code select option.make me confuse

Comment: from browser console, copy the html generated for select, and paste here pls

Comment: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: views/input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 266</p>

Comment: your response 'data' is not an object, make sure it has proper value.
use console.log to print 'data' in success method and check whether it's expected data or not.

Comment: with console.log data show